# Should I preallocate std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, stl, stringstream

I use `std::stringstream` extensively to construct strings and error messages in my application. The `stringstreams` are usually very short life automatic variables.

Will such usage cause heap reallocation for every variable? Should I switch from temporary to class-member `stringstream` variable?

In latter case, how can I reserve `stringstream` buffer? (Should I initialize it with a large enough string or is there a more elegant method?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you profiled your execution, and found them to be a source of slow down?

Consider their usage.  Are they mostly for error messages outside the normal flow of your code?

As far as reserving space...

Some implementations probably reserve a small buffer before any allocation takes place for the stringstream.  Many implementations of std::string do this.

Another option might be (untested!)

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(50);
std::stringstream sstr(str);
```

You might find some more ideas in this [gamedev thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=365745).

**edit:**

Mucking around with the [stringstream's rdbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/rdbuf/) might also be a solution.  This approach is probably Very Easy To Get Wrong though, so please [be sure it's absolutely necessary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29).  Definitely not elegant or concise.

Comment: Good advice; however, reserving 50 then copying that string might instead defeat a small non-heap buffer optimization (if your implementation has one).  If you want to write your own streambuf, then you have precise control over all buffer management; you'd then use ostream (or istream or iostream, but the question indicates output formatting is the concern here) with your streambuf rather than changing a stringstream's buffer through rdbuf.

Comment: I don't think stringstream reserve anything more than `str`'s content length (which is 0) . According to cplusplus.com: "Constructs a ostringstream object with a copy of str as content.". The reference sais "copy of string content". It doesn't explicitly say that it reserves the same amount of memory. I couldn't find any source that says anything about reserving memory using this constructor.

Comment: The constructor you use above is no longer valid. You can see that the no-copy constructor was removed. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/

Comment: You can do it with C++20: std::stringstream sstr(std::move(str)); or avoid a string copy when extracting the result if you are done with the stringstream like this std::move(sstr).str()

Answer (score 5):

Although "mucking around with the [stringstream's rdbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/rdbuf/)...is probably Very Easy To Get Wrong", I went ahead and [hacked together a proof-of-concept](https://godbolt.org/z/VoRpRD) anyway for fun, as it has always bugged me that there is no easy way to `reserve` storage for `stringstream`. Again, as @luke said, you are probably better off optimizing what your profiler tells you needs optimizing, so this is just to address "What if I want to do it anyway?".

Instead of mucking around with [stringstream's rdbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/rdbuf/), I made my own, which does pretty much the same thing. It implements only the minimum, and uses a `string` as a buffer. Don't ask me why I called it a `VECTOR_output_stream`. This is just a quickly-hacked-together thing.

```cpp
constexpr auto preallocated_size = 256;
auto stream = vector_output_stream(preallocated_size);
stream << "My parrot ate " << 3 << " cookies.";
cout << stream.str() << endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

### The Bad

This is an old question, but even as of C++1z/C++2a in `Visual Studio 2019`, `stringstream` has no ideal way of reserving a buffer.

The other answers to this question do not work at all and for the following reasons:

- calling reserve on an empty string yields an empty string, so `stringstream` constructor doesn't need to allocate to copy the contents of that string.
- `seekp` on a `stringstream` still seems to be undefined behavior and/or does nothing.

### The Good

This code segment works as expected, with `ss` being preallocated with the requested size.

```
std::string dummy(reserve, '\0');
std::stringstream ss(dummy);
dummy.clear();
dummy.shrink_to_fit();
```

The code can also be written as a one-liner `std::stringstream ss(std::string(reserve, '\0'));`.

### The Ugly

What really happens in this code segment is the following:

- `dummy` is preallocated with the reserve, and the buffer is subsequently filled with null bytes (required for the constructor).
- `stringstream` is constructed with dummy. This copies the entire string's contents into an internal buffer, which is preallocated.
- `dummy` is then cleared and then erased, freeing up its allocation.

This means that in order to preallocate a `stringstream`, two allocations, one fill, and one copy takes place. The worst part is that during the expression, twice as much memory is needed for the desired allocation. Yikes!

For most use cases, this might not matter at all and it's OK to take the extra fill and copy hit to have fewer reallocations.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I suspect that `stringbuf` of `stringstream` is tightly related with resulted `string`. So I suspect that you can use `ss.seekp(reserved-1); ss.put('\0');` to reserve `reserved` amount of bytes inside of underlying `string` of `ss`. Actually I'd like to see something like `ss.seekp(reserved); ss.trunc();`, but there is no `trunc()` method for streams.

Comment: I have tested it in `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` and seams that raises the `badbit` on. The followed `<<` operators would fail on it.

Comment: I'm usually don't trust behaviour of MSVC. But as per [`seekp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) and [`seekpos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/seekpos) I see no requirements to support or not support that operation. Thus you cannot rely that code to be working equally across different compilers+runtimes, I guess.